# HttpWebRequest throw NameResolutionFailure run in linux mono

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mono, httpwebrequest

i have a `asp.net mvc` project run in linux mono. On my Windows native test is normal, but throws an exception on linux mono. I have tortured for a few days, if you can help me, thank you very much!

This is my code:

```
string strGateway="http:192.168.200.3:6182/getData";

HttpWebRequest myReq=(HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(strGateway) as 
HttpWebRequest;

myReq.Method="POST";

myReq.ContentType="text/xml/charest=UTF-8";

Stream newStream=myReq.GetRequestStream();
newStream.Write(st,0,st.Length);
newStream.Close();
```

Comment: Unclear what you're asking
Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: what version of mono are you using?